# Help me with conditional tenses and could/would usage

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

Correct my sentence if it is wrong please:

> "X could be helpful in a very simple case: **where there is** only one Y of each X type."

How would it be correct to say it in the past?

How to fix this:

> "X could be helpful in a very simple case: **where there was** only one Y of each X type."

Comment: Helpfull => helpful ...

Comment: Let's be honest: I'm totally lost in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking about the way to use the past tense for "could be".

*Could* is a modal, so we use what's technically called the [past modal perfect](http://www.tamiu.edu/uc/writingcenter/documents/VerbFormsExcercise2.pdf), which uses the modal + "have" + a past participle.

To put this sentence in the past, it would be "X **could have been** helpful in a very simple case, where there was only one Y of each X type."

Here's a good reference: [Could have, should have, would have.](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/could-have-should-have-would-have.html)